# Reading from .txt file into two dimensional array in c++ 14

Tags: c++

Trying to store questions from a .txt file with a 2d or 3d array and I can't quite figure it out. The .txt file looks like this

```
Where does a C++ program begin is execution?
The first function in the file
The first function by alphabetic order of names
The function main( )
The function specified in the #DEFINE First Function

How many values can be returned from a function by means of the "return" statement?
1
2
3
Lots and Lots
```

The amount of questions are up to 20 with each one having 4 answers. There are at least one empty lines between questions. I have to display them as well but I can figure that part out.

Comment: This link might help: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/83309/reading-multiple-lines-from-a-txt-file

Comment: Please try to write some code to accomplish your objective. Post that code if you can't make it work and ask specifically about your problem. Otherwise, welcome to stackoverfow!

Comment: You don't have to store them in a 2D array. Why not just make a `struct` and have 5 strings, 1 for question and 1 per answer. 
Then just read in line by line and push those structs into a vector. Would make accessing stuff easy too!

Comment: Or even a slight improvement, have the struct with members a `std::string question` and then `std::array<std::string, 4> answers`.